# How can I use one form for two entities

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, datatemplateselector

How can I use one form for two entities? Sample:

```
entity 1: Name (string), Address (string), Age (int).

entity 2: Name (string), Address (string), Contact (string).
```

Using the same form:

```
Name:

Address: 

?????:
```

The third field is changed based entity. `Age (int)` or `Contact (string)`

Is it possible to use  `DataTemplateSelector` or`Trigger` or something else to do this?

Comment: Could you provide some part of your code?

Answer (score 2):

I would create all 4 controls in the form.

For the latter two:
I would set the `Visibility` property of the control which shall currently not be shown to from `Visible` to `Collapsed` in order to hide it. The other (visible) control will take up the space of the collapsed control.

Example:

```
<StackPanel>

    <StackPanel x:Name="A"></StackPanel>
    <StackPanel x:Name="B"></StackPanel>
    <StackPanel x:Name="C" Visibility="Collapsed"></StackPanel>
    <StackPanel x:Name="D"></StackPanel>       

</StackPanel>
```

You can change the `Visibility` in the code behind file.

A better solution would be to create a binding for the `Visibilty` property to your view model if you have one.